# 1440p monitor at 120hz with only 1 DVI input port. Possible to output with HDMI through HDMI splitter and then convert to DVI?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, dvi, high-resolution, 120hz

I have a 27 inch 2560x1440 Xstar (Korean) monitor, overclocked to 120hz, and it has one dual DVI-D input.

I would like to connect that monitor to my PC, Chromecast and Xbox by using a HDMI splitter like this one: http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00KCPY5Y0/.

Would it be possible to run the configuration below whereby the monitor is @ 120hz and 2560x1440?

---

HDMI Cables

PC,Chrome Cast, Xbox  HDMI CABLE to HDMI SPLITTER BOX to HDMI to DVI ADAPTOR to 27" Monitor 2560x1440 @120hz

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It doesn't have any displayport input for instance?

Answer (score 2):

According to page of that HDMI Switch that you are planning to buy, the HDMI version 1.4 is supported. The maximum speed of the data transfer over HDMI is given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_comparison), as 8.16 Gb/s. Notice that the speed is measured as Gigabits per second.

Now, what you want to render is 2560x1440 at 120hz. Calculating the bandwidth required:

2560 x 1440 x 120 x 24 = 10616832000 bits/s

This is approximately 10.62 Gbit/s ([1 Gb/s = 1,000,000,000 bits/s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gbit/s#Gigabit_per_second)). This is more than what HDMI v1.4 is said to be capable. So, it might not be possible to render at such a high fps.